# Bulk video clip edits.

Tags: video, time-lapse

I am currently working on a timelapse project for a client in the construction business. I did not shoot the timelapse, but have all the video files on my computer. The camera that was used has a "warmup" time if you will, and the videos have a "fade in" effect. As you can probably tell, this presents a problem as the videos will be sped up rapidly, and it will create a strobe effect. I have hundreds of individual videos that need trimmed to get rid of this effect. Does anyone know of any software that will allow you to apply bulk edits to a large batch of videos? This would save me lots of monotonous labor going through one by one and trimming the clips. Any suggestions would be appreciated.